# What do the values in /admin/utils/phpinfo mean?

Tags: control-panel

When two values are displayed for PHP Info, what does that mean? For example,[image: memory_limit 256M/128M]

Why the two values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a formatting bug in Craft.  We're parsing the output of a call to [phpinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php), so one of them is probably coming from the "Local Value" column and the other is coming from the "Master Value" column.

Comment: Do you know which one is which?

Comment: Looks like the upper one is the "Local Value" (which is the one in effect)

Answer (score 2):

I just made a change on my server (DigitalOcean w/ ServerPilot) which resulted in a double-value... Before my change, there was only a single value.

[image: max_input_vars]

I can confirm that **the top value is overriding the bottom value**.

My server default was set to 1000. I used a `.user.ini` file to override that to 5000.

> **ServerPilot: How to Change PHP Settings**
>
> https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-change-php-settings.html